# MS Unit tests executes twice (also fails on 2nd execution) on build server

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, tfs, build

We have

-> a .Net Application (using Framework 4.6.2 and VS2015), for which we have 1075 MS unit test cases.

-> 2 TFS Build servers (Lets serverA and serverB) on which we run & create builds for our App.

## Issue:

When we trigger build on serverA then build executes successfully and all 1075 test cases executes single time successfully.

But on serverB first all 1075 test cases executes successfully, and then it executes few test cases again and all those repeated test case fails.

All Test cases fails with message:   Test method TestMethodName threw exception System.BadImageFormatException, but exception System.IndexOutOfRangeException was expected. Exception message: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyProject.Maths, Version=9.2.161.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8ve3d5d1cc33a581' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

## Query:

Why serverB executing few test cases again?

Why the repeated test cases getting failed?

The main concern is that for both servers, we are using same Build definition and same build template. So, the issue is not occurring on build definition side, it should be an issue on build serverB configuration.

All answers I read are suggesting changes either in build defination or build template or some software un-installation , while other suggested Your test project is refereed by multiple project (which is not the case) , but nothing works as of now.

Also, if I assume that there might be some issue on my code/build template side, but again ubit-test cases runs successfully on other server.

Could you please help, what could be probable reason.

Comment: Are you sure serverA and  server B have the same  SDK/Components installed and configured? Please check that first.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for your response. I am looking into the same. Meanwhile question that troubling me is what settings/software on ServerB, are causing Unit Test Cases to run twice. Since same project with same build deifination exexutes test cases only once on ServerA. If you could throw some light on it, would be very grateful.

Comment: Not sure about that, that's just for your troubleshooting, based on your description it should be something dirrerent with the server B. So, you can have a try with other servers, or create a new build defintion to check that again, or try the things mentioned in below answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure Server A and Sever B have the same configuration.

Whatever, based on the error message "`System.BadImageFormatException`..." It should be the incompatibilities issue.

> Ultimately, System.BadImageFormatExceptions are an indication of
>   incompatible versioning. For many modern software applications, major
>   versions of often include breaking compatibility issues, preventing
>   backward compatibility with some aspects of previous versions. .NET
>   assemblies (.dlls or .exes) are much the same, and attempting to make
>   use of two different types of assemblies that contain
>   incompatibilities will often generate a
>   System.BadImageFormatException.
>
> The first (and arguably most common) way to raise a
>   System.BadImageFormatException is when attempting to make use of an
>   unmanaged assembly, as if it were an assembly created with the .NET
>   Framework. Unmanaged assemblies are assemblies that have been
>   generated from code that is not handled and compiled by the common
>   language runtime of .NET. This includes many older applications and
>   assemblies, particularly those created for 32-bit systems.
>
> Another way we might throw a System.BadImageFormatException is when
>   trying to load an assembly that was compiled using a different CPU
>   type than what we’re executing .NET on currently.
>
> Lastly, we also run into trouble if we attempt to load an assembly
>   that was compiled using a much older version of .NET (such as .NET
>   1.1)
>
> ***Source here: [.NET Exception Handling – System.BadImageFormatException](https://airbrake.io/blog/dotnet-exception-handling/system-badimageformatexception)***

Also this article for your reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7137bfe.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

So, please try below items to check if that works for you:

- Enable **Clean** Option in your build definition. (Both Repository
  tab and Build Task step )
- check if the **Target Platform** of your test project matches that
  of the project you are testing.
  Right-click your project and select '**Properties**' --> Select the
  '**Build**' tab on the left --> Change to x86/x64/AnyCPU separately
  to check that again.